# Subquery returned more than 1 value. this is not permitted when the subquery follows = or when the subquery is used as an expression?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to update multiple tables and values after inserting values in one table so I created a trigger. It works fine for inserts of one row, but as soon I insert more rows, SQL Server gives me  following error:

> subquery returned more than 1 value. this is not permitted when the subquery follows =  or when the subquery is used as an expression?

Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tbl_Sales_ForInsert]
ON [dbo].[SALES] 
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ITEMMODEL varchar(100)

  SELECT @ITEMMODEL = ITEM_MODEL FROM inserted

  UPDATE SALES 
  SET PROFIT = TOTAL_PRICE - (SELECT QUANTITY FROM SALES WHERE ITEM_MODEL = @ITEMMODEL) * (SELECT RATE FROM ITEM_DETAILS WHERE ITEM_MODEL = @ITEMMODEL) 
  WHERE ITEM_MODEL = @ITEMMODEL

  UPDATE ITEM_DETAILS 
  SET QUANTITY = QUANTITY - (SELECT QUANTITY FROM SALES WHERE ITEM_MODEL = @ITEMMODEL) 
  WHERE ITEM_MODEL = @ITEMMODEL

  --UPDATE ITEM_DETAILS SET AMOUNT = AMOUNT - (SELECT RATE FROM ITEM_DETAILS WHERE ITEM_MODEL=@ITEMMODEL) * (SELECT QUANTITY FROM SALES WHERE ITEM_MODEL=@ITEMMODEL) where ITEM_MODEL=@ITEMMODEL
END
```

As I insert data in `SALES` table for 1st time the update got successful but for 2nd time it gives me above error remember `ITEM_MODEL` is foreign key constraint in SALES table.

I have been suffering with this error can anyone help me please?

Comment: are your foreign keys unique?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your fundamental flaw is that you seem to expect the trigger to be fired **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case in SQL Server. Instead, the trigger fires **once per statement**, and the pseudo table `Inserted` might contain **multiple rows**.

Given that that table might contain multiple rows - which one do you expect will be selected here??

```
SELECT @ITEMMODEL = ITEM_MODEL FROM inserted
```

It's undefined - you might get the values from arbitrary rows in `Inserted`.

You need to rewrite your entire trigger with the knowledge the `Inserted` **WILL** contain multiple rows! You need to work with set-based operations - don't expect just a single row in `Inserted`!

So in your case, your trigger code should look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tbl_Sales_ForInsert]
ON [dbo].[SALES] 
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   -- update the dbo.Sales table, set "PROFIT" to the difference of 
   -- TOTAL_PRICE and (QUANTITY * RATE) from the "Inserted" pseudo table
   UPDATE s
   SET s.PROFIT = i.TOTAL_PRICE - (i.QUANTITY * i.RATE) 
   FROM dbo.Sales s
   INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.ITEM_MODEL = s.ITEM_MODEL

   -- update the dbo.ITEM_DETAILS table
   UPDATE id
   SET id.QUANTITY = id.QUANTITY - i.Quantity
   FROM dbo.ITEM_DETAILS id
   INNER JOIN Inserted i ON id.ITEM_MODEL = i.ITEM_MODEL
END
```

Comment: I can't describe how much I appreciate your answer. I was working with SQL Server for many years and was thinking there is no way to make multiple updates in table which has a trigger. But you showed that the Insert can have multiple rows and SQL Server can do multiple insertion and updates on table with triggers. THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

Marc_s is right about expecting the inserted pseudo table containing more than one row. There are instances that a query might work if a subquery was just limited to one row with a TOP(1).

```
  UPDATE SALES 
  SET PROFIT = TOTAL_PRICE - (SELECT TOP(1) QUANTITY FROM SALES WHERE ITEM_MODEL = @ITEMMODEL) 
  * (SELECT TOP(1) RATE FROM ITEM_DETAILS WHERE ITEM_MODEL = @ITEMMODEL) 
  WHERE ITEM_MODEL = @ITEMMODEL
```